# Unable to purchase grouped products after editing view.phtml - Magento

Tags: magento

I'm having a problem trying to purchase any product that is part of a grouped product. I read through many forums and tried what I've found not none are helping. I only moved the "grouped" items under the short description because it defaults to being above the short description. After I have moved the group items and try to purchase the products, I get an error message saying "Please specify the quantity of product(s)." When clearly a quantity is specified.

Please see my code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magentocommerce.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magentocommerce.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    design
 * @package     base_default
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2013 Magento Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */

/**
 * Product view template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
 * @see Mage_Review_Block_Product_View
 */
?>

<?php $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output'); ?>

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);

</script>

<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>

<div class="product-view">

    <div class="product-essential">

    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>

        <?php echo $this->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>

        <div class="no-display">

            <input type="hidden" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>" />

            <input type="hidden" name="related_product" id="related-products-field" value="" />

        </div>

        <div class="product-shop">

            <div class="product-name">

                <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>

            </div>

          <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, false, true)?>

             <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('alert_urls') ?>



          <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
                <div class="short-description">
                    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?></h2>
                    <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
                </div>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $this->getTierPriceHtml() ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extrahint') ?>
            <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
               <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
           <?php endif; ?>
           <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('other');?>
           <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
                 <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
            <?php endif;?>

<div class="email-social">

  <?php if ($this->canEmailToFriend()): ?>
                <p class="email-friend"><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/product')->getEmailToFriendUrl($_product) ?>"><?php echo $this->__('Email to a Friend') ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

           <div class="social-links">    
          <div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
            <a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
            <a class="addthis_button_pinterest_pinit"></a>
            <a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
            </div>
            <script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_addressbar":false};</script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-51b4ffaf24755410"></script>
         </div>

        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="product-img-box">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('media') ?>
        </div>

        <div class="clearer"></div>
        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container2', '', true, true) ?>
        <?php endif;?>

    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[
       var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);

        productAddToCartForm.submitLight = function(button, url){
            if(this.validator) {

               var nv = Validation.methods;
                delete Validation.methods['required-entry'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required'];
                delete Validation.methods['validate-one-required-by-name'];
                // Remove custom datetime validators
                for (var methodName in Validation.methods) {
                    if (methodName.match(/^validate-datetime-.*/i)) {
                        delete Validation.methods[methodName];
                    }
                }

                if (this.validator.validate()) {
                    if (url) {
                        this.form.action = url;
                    }
                    this.form.submit();
                }
                Object.extend(Validation.methods, nv);
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
    //]]>
    </script>
    </div>
  <div>
    <form action="<?php echo $this->getSubmitUrl($_product) ?>" method="post" id="product_addtocart_form"<?php if($_product->getOptions()): ?> enctype="multipart/form-data"<?php endif; ?>>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data') ?>
    </form>
  </div>

    <div class="product-collateral">
<?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
        <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
            <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
            <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
            <?php endif;?>
            <?php echo $html; ?>
        </div>
<?php endforeach;?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_additional_data') ?>
    </div>

</div>
```

EDIT: I am using Magento Version 1.8

Comment: What version of Magento? Can't diff against the original unless we know that to see exactly what was changed. Otherwise it becomes a tldr; because of the extra guesswork.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using Magento Version 1.8